# Is there a way to preserve api response data while modifying parts of it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

In some situations, I want to validate data in a React application by comparing the current state with the original data obtained from the API. I have issues preserving the original data when I need to modify a nested element inside an array.

For example, with this data:

```
{
  id: 1,
  items: [{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}]
}
```

And the following React component excerpt:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    originalData: null,
    items: [],
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  Api.get("/data").then(res => {
    this.setState({
      originalData: res.data,
      items: res.data.items,
    }
  });  
}
```

If `this.state.items[0]` becomes `{name: "baz"}`, `this.state.originalData.items[0]` will also be modified. I tried to use `res.data.items.slice()` and `[...res.data.items]` to make a copy of the array when setting the `this.state.items` but it did not help.

The two solutions I can see are:

1. Call the API to get the original data when it's time to validate the current state
2. Use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data))` to store a new object not referencing `res.data` inside `this.state.originalData`.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I believe you are looking to deep-clone an object – related reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: You need to deep clone the array of objects somehow.